# MongoDB document streaming with HTTP response?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, mongoose, derbyjs

After an all day research on node.js real-time frameworks/wrappers (derby.js, meteor,
socketIO...) I realised, that the more old-fashioned (sorry) way of a restful API 
fits all my needs.

One of the reasons I thought I have to use an ongoing socket connection was because I want to
stream my MongoDB documents from the database instead of loading them all into memory on the server. I think this is the recommended way because it minimizes the use of server ressources.

But here is the problem:

Does a simple document query streaming work with the ordinary HTTP request/response 
model or do we have to establish an ongoing socket-connection to stream all documents to the client?

Note: I only have to load the documents on an ajax call - without the need to have new
documents to be pushed to the client (so really no need to be realtime).

Is there anything special to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stream the results of the query using the standard HTTP request/response APIs.

The general sequence of calls is:

```
res.writeHead(<header content>)
res.write(<data>)
...
res.write(<data>)
res.end();
```

But you make those calls asynchronously, driven by the streaming events from your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. While I read about the play framework 2 hours ago, I saw the notion of having the encoding of the HTTP response header to be set to "chunk".

Then, when I analyzed some express.js made sites I saw that this was used too - so express seems to leverage "chunks" as its default.

So while the mongoDB documents are fetched from the database, delivered as a stream all documents can be put into the HTTP response (being the "chunks"). When the stream ends, the HTTP response is marked as finished and ready to be presented. 

I think this is exactly the same as you mentioned, true?